# grep cannot find a known string in a MS-Word file even with the -a option

Tags: microsoft-word, grep

I have MS-Word file including the string "Abekat"
The entire content of the file (test.docx) is in fact just: "This file includes the word Abekat".
Standing in the same directory as my target file (test.docx) and performing the terminal command

```
grep -ia Abekat *
```

I simply get no response. 
I don't understand why this is the case.
I hope someone can explain that to me.
(I am running macOS (10:15.4)
Best
Eigil

Answer (score 1):

It’s partly because a .docx file is actually a .zip file, which is compressed, so the sequence of characters Abekat does not exist in the .zip file (or if it did, it would be “by accident”)

Even if you unzip the .docx file, which should give you a folder structure containing a number of files such as .xml, .rels and others, running grep against those files may not find the word Abekat.

That’s because word sometimes divides a piece of contiguous text into separate “runs”. Each run is surrounded by xml tags, so your text might look something like `<w:r><w:t>Abe</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>kat</w:t></w:r>` . For example, if the text “kat” had different formatting from “Abe”, it would be in a separate run with some extra XML elements That described the formatting. But sometimes it is is not obvious why Word has divided a text into 2 runs.

If you are just using grep to try to find files that contain a certain string, you may be better off using mdfind instead - it’s the command-line equivalent of Mac OS Spotlight. (I’ve never used it myself)

Comment: Thanks a lot. mdfind worked fine. Wonder why it is not more known and not the first assist you get when "googling" for find a string on a mac.

Comment: It did not work for my system files (and mail boxes), though. Then I guess I will need to temporarily (with reboot) disablbe System Integrity Protection (SIP) - and of course re-enable SIP again with a new boot after making the search!

Comment: @Eigil Kass: interesting, I assume that using "sudo" didn't help?

Comment: Yes, sudo was not enough!

Comment: mdfind is amazing! Sorry you never got an upvote/accept from the OP, you deserved it!